# Replace first word with third one in every line, but words are separated by ":"

Tags: sed

I'm trying to learn sed but getting stuck when trying to replace first word wih the 3rd. I was thinking about the above code, but it doesn't work.
Also, is there any way of splitting the line if the words are separated by ":" using sed?

```
sed "s/\(^[a-z,0-9]*\) \(.*\) \([a-z,0-9]*\)/\1 \2 \1/"
```

Comment: `sed "s/^\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) [^ ]*/\1 \2 \1/"` but it is "simpler" with `awk`

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew, that was helpful! I added the separator and that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment below it sounds like you actually want to replace the third word with the first one rather than the other way around. If so then:

```
$ echo 'first:second:third' | sed 's/\(\([^:]*\).*:\).*/\1\2/'
first:second:first
```

or if you have many fields to manipulate:

```
$ echo 'first:second:third' | sed 's/\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\)/\1:\2:\1/'
first:second:first
```

but you should really use awk for anything involving fields anyway:

```
$ echo 'first:second:third' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$3=$1} 1'
first:second:first
```

Comment: that's what I wanted, only with 1:\2:\1:/ instead. Thank you very much!

Comment: you're right. I was thinking about replacing the third word with the first one, and wrote the opposite. Thanks again!

Comment: I really like @ed-morton answer it is smart and concise.
I wish to add a little readability enhancement to the the sed command.


`echo 'first:second:third:forth:fifth' | sed -r 's|([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]*)|\1:\2:\1|' `

Comment: cool @DudiBoy, great idea to use pipes. Can you please explain what ([^:]+) refer to? I know ^ is beggining of line, but what about the :? Also, I tried to use [a-z,0-9] instead, so I look for words with letters and digits only, and not characters, but it didn't work.

Comment: () is a matching group to be referenced later in \1 \2 \3. [] is character selection group, in the [] the ^ is negating the match. So the [^:] is match all characters not : . + is multiplication selector for one or more.  * is multiplication selector for zero or more. [^:]+ is selecting all non : characters, one or more times.